# How do I set custom parameters for Twilio TVOCallInvite on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

I'm trying to pass custom parameters in call invite structure but don't receive them on the recipient side.

```
let connectOptions: TVOConnectOptions = TVOConnectOptions(accessToken: token) { (builder) in
    builder.params = ["To": "Recipeint Id",
                      "From": "Caller name"]
    builder.uuid = uuid
}

self.call = TwilioVoice.connect(with: connectOptions, delegate: self)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add logic in backend or you can say server code for the same.

Link for server code in node 
https://github.com/twilio/voice-quickstart-server-node

need to modify below function

```
function makeCall(request, response) {

  // The recipient of the call, a phone number or a client

  var to = null;

  if (request.method == 'POST') {

    to = request.body.to;
    callerId = request.body.from; //--> new added line for caller name
  } else {

    to = request.query.to;
    callerId = request.body.from; //--> new added line for caller name
  }




  const voiceResponse = new VoiceResponse();




  if (!to) {

      voiceResponse.say("Congratulations! You have made your first call! Good bye.");

  } else if (isNumber(to)) {

      const dial = voiceResponse.dial({callerId : callerNumber});

      dial.number(to);

  } else {

      const dial = voiceResponse.dial({callerId : callerId});

      dial.client(to);

  }

  console.log('Response:' + voiceResponse.toString());

  return response.send(voiceResponse.toString());

}
```

also need make var instead of const for `callerId` variable , and If you are passing caller name then node code format should save value in this format

```
'client:callername'
```

i.e. `client:` and after that value which is being passed from iOS app

Answer (score 1):

Gave up actually with this idea... Followed this [instruction](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/373162#373438) so that the app reports a call to CallKit and then updates the caller name after that.